# Singleton Windows Phone Native App

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

How can I make sure there is only 1 running instance of my C# native app (RT) running on the device at anyone time?

If this was a desktop app there would be many ways to do this.

I have Googled but cannot find anything.  It could just be I am not putting the right search parameters in though!

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There can only ever be one instance of your app running at any time anyway.

Comment: hmmm, thanks.  I am thinking then it is because the flow of my pages are erratic.  I use back buttons in my app and also the back button on the phone itself. I use: Frame.GoBack(); to go back to the previous page. Is that correct?  thanks

Comment: Yes. What is the specific problem you are having? Do you have an issue with page navigation?